# newline to table content (bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, fetch

beginner javascript programmer here, i'm having difficulties changing position(or actually newline) of table's content, in the code below is there easy way to make 'emp future' come under those others ('emp mygoals' and 'emp id') whether with newline or positioning ( if could put both ways so people could learn). I tried with newlines and position but json data disappeared. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style>
    </style>
 
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-stripped"> 
     <thead>
     <tr> 
         <th> emp id</th>
      <th> emp mygoals</th>
          <th> emp future</th>

     </tr> 
  </thead>
 
 
      <tbody id="data" >
 </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


    <script>
  fetch("https://asdasd.free.beeceptor.com/a",
              {
              method: "GET",
              headers: {
                 "x-api-key": "p*****w"
              }
            }
          ).then(res =>{ 

        res.json().then(
  data=> {
  console.log(data);
  var temp ="";
  
       temp +="<tr>";
    temp += "<td>"+data.id+"</td>";
    temp += "<td>"+data.mygoals+"</td>";
    temp += "<td>"+data.future+"</td></tr>";

     document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = temp
  }
   )
    }
  )
 .catch(err => {
          console.log("ERROR: " + err);
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, are you trying to append values to the table via successive calls to the javascript function that fetches new results for you?

```
<script>
fetch("https://asdasd.free.beeceptor.com/a", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "x-api-key": "p*****w"
    }
}).then(res => { 
    res.json().then(data => {
        //Here assuming that data is an array of objects
        //var data = : { "id": "145127236", "mygoals": "success", "future": "high", "dole": { "Key": "fhd699f" } },

        ids = document.getElementById("ids")
        goals = document.getElementById("goals")
        futures = document.getElementById("futures")

        ids.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<td>" + data.id + "</td>");
        goals.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<td>" + data.mygoals + "</td>");
        futures.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<td>" + data.futures + "</td>");

    }
  )
}).catch(err => {
      console.log("ERROR: " + err);
});
</script>
```

Notice that I've changed the `innerHtml = temp` for `.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", temp);`. This appends the content of the temp variable instead of replacing the html of #data with the value of temp.

EDIT: Changing the layout of the table according to the responsive tables in Bootstrap 4.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-stripped">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th id="ids">emp id</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th id="goals">emp goals</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th id="futures">emp futures</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here I set up a fiddle with a simple demo without bootstrap [base demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zb3vg6aq/)

Comment: in table i have these : '<th> emp id</th><th> emp mygoals</th>
<th> emp future</th>'. Those are next to each other, i want to have one of them to come under the other like newline (one below the other). (\n, <br> ?)

Comment: Do you mean you want to layout your table horizontally instead of vertically?

emp id | id1 | id2 | ... | \n
emp mygoals | goal1 | goal2 | ... | \n
emp future | future1 | future2 | ... | \n

It seems that comments in stackoverflow don't format well the newlines i'm trying to insert.

Comment: If you have a lot of data and you don't want to make a very large vertical scroll mabye you can using bootstrap check out the always responsive style: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#always-responsive. Then you can change the layout of the table to be horizontal instead of vertical as you first posted, and display the remaining data with a horizontal scroll.

Comment: could you make it like you  described above ?

Comment: Now the markup has changed. You may add the id "data" to the tbody element as it was before. You will also have to change the code after the promise is resolved because now the html that you need to append is different.

Comment: could you possibly edit code to 'You will also have to change the code after the promise is resolved' cause i'm beginner on this, then i will accept ur answer

Comment: unfortunately wont work for me cuz my data is not array its object

Comment: No problem. Wanna add a more detailed example?

Comment: this is my json : { "id": "145127236", "mygoals": "success", "future": "high", "dole": { "Key": "fhd699f" } }

Comment: any luck with the modified code? hope you can solve it :)